# Variance becomes negative

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

Say I've an operator $\hat \sigma_{11} = |1\rangle \langle1|$. Now say we calculate the variance of $\hat \sigma_{11}$. So we have,

$$\langle (\Delta\hat \sigma_{11})^2 \rangle = \langle \hat \sigma_{11}^2 \rangle - \langle \hat \sigma_{11} \rangle^2 = \langle \hat \sigma_{11} \rangle - \
\langle \hat \sigma_{11} \rangle^2 \le 0.$$

So a positive definite quantity becomes negative? Where is the fallacy in my reasoning?

Comment: Don't you need to specify a state too? Operators themselves don't have means and variances.

Comment: How does $\langle \hat \sigma_{11}^2 \rangle - \langle \hat \sigma_{11} \rangle^2 = \langle \hat \sigma_{11} \rangle - \
\langle \hat \sigma_{11} \rangle^2$?  Alternatively, $\langle\hat \sigma_{11}^2\rangle \ne \langle\hat \sigma_{11}\rangle$.

Comment: @BioPhysicist that's already a state: a pure state $|1\rangle$ described by density operator $\hat\sigma_{11}$.

Comment: @Ruslan What's already a state?

Comment: @BioPhysicist $|1\rangle\langle1|$. That was a reply to your previous comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about math

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator $\hat\sigma_{11}$ is a projection operator onto the space spanned by $|1\rangle$. Geometrically it's easy to see that the projection of a vector will always be shorter than the vector itself, and this is true in general for projection operators. So the expectation value $\langle\hat\sigma_{11}\rangle$ is necessarily smaller than one. Hence $\langle\hat\sigma_{11}\rangle^2 < \langle\hat\sigma_{11}\rangle$ and your variance will always be non-negative.

Comment: Projection will always make the vector shorter. True. But how does that make $\langle \hat \sigma \rangle < 0$. Could you please explain?

Comment: I think he meant smaller than 1.

Comment: Correct, I meant smaller than one, my mistake.

Comment: An important ingredient here is that the spectrum of any non-trivial projection $P \neq 0 , \mathbf{1}$ is $\{ 0 , 1\}$. That means the expectation value lies inside the interval $[ 0 , 1]$ and on $[0,1]$ the function $x - x^2 = x(1-x) \geq 0$ is non-negative.